# pandas read_json to_json methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider you have like:

`json_df = df.to_json(orient='table')`
Now you do:

`df_again = pd.read_json(json_df,orient='table', dtype=True)`

As you know when choosing `orient=table` you get a `schema` of the fields by type.

So my question is like that: if I call the `read json` like this way instead:
`df_again = pd.read_json(df,orient='table', dtype=False)`

Does it mean that now we are not using that `schema` part in order to conclude regarding types of columns.
Or the `dtype` parameter uses another mechanism (not using `schema` metadata) to guess types when building again the dataframe? if so what is the purpose of the schema metadata , being added by using the `orient='table'` parameter.

**Example**:
`import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [56], "col2":["testing"], "col3": [1.7], "col4":["1234"]})
json_df = df.to_json(orient='table')
df_again = pd.read_json(json_df,orient='table', dtype=True)`
or

`df_again = pd.read_json(json_df,orient='table', dtype=False)`

Comment: Not sure what your question is here. Yes, `dtypes=True` will try to infer dtypes. Yes, `dtypes=False` is not going to do any inference, so the columns will be loaded as objects.

Comment: What do you mean will be loaded like objects, and if dtypes=True does it trying to infer using the schema created by parameter `orient='table'`? Please try convert dataframe using this method and see

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? I can't reproduce what you are talking about if there is nothing to reproduce.

Comment: @coldspeed: you got it

Comment: Hmm, interesting. You will see `df_again.dtypes` shows different output depending on whether `dtype=True` or `False`.

Comment: @coldspeed: yeah, that's my issue, also I wonder what is the purpose of the schema part after the `to_json` if it takes into account by the `dtype` parameter value

Comment: Yeah, this is undocumented behaviour. May or may not be a bug. You will have to do some [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/io/json/json.py#L224-L428) diving to see.